# Python str.maketrans Remove Punctuation with Empty Space

Tags: python, string, text, data-cleaning

I am using *maketrans* from *string module* in Python 3 to do simple text preprocessing like lowering, removing digits and punctuations. The problem is that during the punctuation removal all words are attached together with no empty space! For example, let's say I have the following text:

```
text='[{"Hello":"List:","Test"321:[{"Hello":"Airplane Towel for Kitchen"},{"Hello":2 "&nbsp;Repair massive utilities&nbsp;"2},{"Hello":"Some 3 appliance for our kitchen"2}'
```

text=text.lower()
text=text.translate(str.maketrans(' ',' ',string.digits))

Works just fine, it gives:

```
'[{"hello":"list:","test":[{"hello":"airplane towel for kitchen"},{"hello": "&nbsp;repair massives utilities&nbsp;"},{"hello":"some  appliance for our kitchen"}'
```

But once I want to remove the punctuations:

```
text=text.translate(str.maketrans(' ',' ',string.punctuation))
```

It gives me this:

```
'hellolisttesthelloairplane towel for kitchenhello nbsprepair massives utilitiesnbsphellosome  appliance for our kitchen'
```

Ideally it should yield:

```
'hello list test hello airplane towel for kitchen hello nbsp repair massives utilities nbsp hello some  appliance for our kitchen'
```

There is not specific reason I am doing it with maketrans, but I like as it is fast and easy and kind of stuck solving it. Thanks!

Disclaimer: I already know how to do it with *re* like the following:

```
import re
s = "string.]With. Punctuation?"
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s)
```

Comment: The output makes sense to me. `hello":"list` doesn't have any spaces between "hello" and "list", so if you remove all the punctuation from it, of course it becomes `hellolist`. I don't think you can remove all punctuation and replace it with exactly one space using only maketrans. You _could_ replace all punctuation with the same number of spaces, so `hello":"list` becomes `hello[three spaces]list`, but that hardly seems ideal.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I thought there might a trick that add empty space after removing punctuations as is possible in re.sub! I guess I waisted sometime figuring out new method while re could do the job easily. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... this works

```
txt = text.translate(str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))).replace(' '*4, ' ').replace(' '*3, ' ').replace(' '*2, ' ').strip()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, it seems you manually tweak it somehow I do not fully understand! ;-)

Comment: Worked for me but can you explain the logic behind replace. @deadvoid

Comment: `text.translate(str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation)))` translated any punctuation within `text` to whitespace, so using `replace(' '*4, ' ')` is to replace 4 consecutive whitespace to single one, `replace(' '*3, ' ')` from 3 to 1, and so on; then `strip` to eliminate the whitespaces before & after.